# OfficeJS Word add-in development: Office.context.document.getFilePropertiesAsync() in Firefox always results in status = error

Tags: office-js, word-addins

I am hoping some OfficeJS folks are around to identify if this is a known issue in FF for the Word Add-in API.
Given code

```
 private getFilePropertiesAsync() {
    Office.context.document.getFilePropertiesAsync((asyncResult: AsyncResult<Office.FileProperties>) => {
        if ((Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded !== asyncResult.status)) {
            this.logger.error(asyncResult.error.message);
        } else {
            // do stuff
        }
    });
}
```

the asyncResult.status in Firefox is always "Failed" status. Any Chromium browser or IE (or desktop) is fine.

`Office.context.document.getFileAsync()` seems to be fine in FF (and everywhere else), which is what makes me suspect `getFilePropertiesAsync()` may have a bug. I didn't turn up anything meaningful on the MS Forums.

Happen to be using Angular 8 for the taskpane app in FF 84, Win 10 1909. Coworker sees the same behavior for this add-in

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the snippet as below in your Script Lab? I tried it in FF, and it works fine.

```js
function getFilePropertiesAsync() {
  Office.context.document.getFilePropertiesAsync(function (asyncResult) {
    if ((Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded !== asyncResult.status)) {
      this.logger.error(asyncResult.error.message);
    } else {
      console.log(asyncResult.status.toString());
      var fileUrl = asyncResult.value.url;
      if (fileUrl == "") {
        console.log("The file hasn't been saved yet. Save the file and try again");
      }
      else {
        console.log(fileUrl);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Office version: 16.0.13911.41002

FF: 86.0.1 (64-bit)

Comment: the problem is prior to checking if the fileUrl is valid. Since asyncResult.status is always "failed" (I'll go edit my original post from: "is always an error" to: "is Failed" to be more clear), you never get into the else to check the url.

At this point I'm up to FF 87 & Office 16.0.13127.21210 with an O365 sub.
And this is specifically about Word, just in case other products behave a little differently.